# Methods to account/correct for dropouts in intervention study

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, intervention-analysis, mnar

I have depression scores for patients before and after intervention, there is no control sample. I want to assess if demographics have an effect on recovery, and I was thinking of doing a linear regression, linear mixed model or quantile regression. My problem is that there are several dropouts (30% of the cases)  and ignoring these cases would be misleading as missing values are not missing at random. What methods could be applied in this context to account/correct for dropouts?

Comment: You coul try survival analysis.

Comment: Thank you @user2974951. Sounds like that would solve part of the problem only. My understanding is that survival analysis would only allow to compare dropouts vs survival, but it would not allow me to gain any insights from cases that finished treatment and show differences in recovery. Furthermore, I just have two points of measurement so not sure if survival analysis would be appropriate.

Comment: That is not true, dropouts would be coded as censored, your target variable would still be survival (recovery). You only need 1 point for this analysis (time at consoring or event / recovery), you would need multiple time points only if you have time-dependent variables.

Comment: @user2974951 Are you proposing a censored model? My concern with censored models is that a dropout is not really a censored value, it is a missing value. We do not actually know what the final depression score would have been for those cases, as treatment was not finished. However it is likely that they dropped out because treatment was not working, i.e., likely that value would have been high if they had finished, so they are missing values not at random. Not sure if I am missing something, if so it would be great if you could point me out/describe the model you have in mind. Thanks!

Comment: That would be a problem, if the censoring is informative, it's still better then nothing. You could do something like http://thestatsgeek.com/2016/07/28/multiple-imputation-for-informative-censoring-r-package/

Comment: @user2974951 the hsu method is very interesting! I was thinking of modeling the depression score as a continuous variable, but my failure here could be patients "recovery" i.e., having a depression score lower than a threshold. Just need to think about the fact that this estimates time to failure and I only have 2 points in time. Thanks, this was certainly helpful!